# Calibrating multi monitor setup

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, calibration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Monitor Calibration Tools and Software](https://superuser.com/questions/22832/monitor-calibration-tools-and-software)

So I recently finished my multiple monitor setup (Thanks to the wonderful Display Fusion, courtesy of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/138658/windows-7-dual-monitor-setup-wallpaper-alignment) answer) . My biggest issue at this point is that it's glaringly obvious that the monitors are not calibrated so that color, brightness, saturation, etc are uniform across them.

I already did the obvious --- reducing the brightness from the obscenely high factory defaults to something more reasonable. I then pulled up a blank copy of notepad on each monitor and calibrated the color output (RGB "user mode" color temperature) so that each monitor *looked* like they had the same color temperature.

Then I tweaked the brightness/contrast/saturation/color temp using a contrasty image, a high saturation image, and a dark image. The dark image was important so that I wasn't getting banding effects from poor settings.

At this point, I've done everything "by hand." Are there any (free) tools which I can install, or fashion MacGyver style that will make it easier to get the monitors to be reasonably calibrated with each other?

I don't need the monitors to necessarily be "color accurate." The most I ever do that would require such a thing is light (read: non-professional) photo editing and *lots* of movie watching. I do however want the monitors to be reasonably uniform and not have blatantly stupid settings that makes them look horrendous like those floor models you see at computer stores.

My hand calibration only goes so far. Despite my best efforts, it's still pretty noticeable that each monitor has a different brightness, color temperature, and contrast.

Comment: I hate to tell you this, but I think that might be as far as you can get. Even identical monitors will have noticeable differences in color temperature.

Comment: @Hassan: I figured as much. I was just wondering if there any tools which make this sort of calibration at least *easier*.

Comment: please tag your question with the correct OS.  The solution - if there is a software solution to this - will differ per OS.